# How do I get the Pin to change it's image?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have the problem, that my Annotation is still a pin! I want the Button and the picture, for the information displayed about the User and it works. But it doesn't change the look of the pin on the Map!
This is my annotationView:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // 1
    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"

    // 2
    if annotation.isKindOfClass(pinAnnotation.self) {
        // 3
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {


            //4
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true


            // 5
            let btn = UIButton(type: .InfoDark)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn



            resultImgArray[0].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45))
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView

                }


            }


        } else {
            // 6
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }

    return nil
```

}

This is my pinAnnotationView.swift as MKAnnotationView:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class pinAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    override init(frame :CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        var frame = self.frame
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
        self.frame = frame
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-5, -5)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        UIImage(named: "carlogo.png")?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30))

    }
}
```

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: Can we see the actual and expected image

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3j1u.png

This is the red Pin with its attributes! The red pin should look like the car logo!

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation.isMember(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
            return nil
        }
        let identifier = "someID"
        var dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        if dequeuedAnnotationView == nil{
            dequeuedAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            configureDetailView(annotationView: dequeuedAnnotationView!)

        }
        return dequeuedAnnotationView
    }    

func configureDetailView(annotationView: MKAnnotationView) {
            var frame = self.frame
            frame.size = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
            self.frame = frame
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-5, -5)
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"yourImage")       
    }
```

And use  annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = "yourView" in this case will be frame.

I hope works for you